# Ансамбль Деревьев решений

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Как называется способ обучения ансамбля деревьев решений, который заключается в том что мы делим обучающую выборку по признакам и обучаем часть классификаторов ансамбля на одном наборе признаков а другую часть ансамбля на другом наборе признаков? Есть ли примеры на Python?

Comment: Это относиться не только к ансамблю, блочная перекрестная проверка применима к любой модели. И делить надо не по признакам а по частям. Там же смысл в том, что бы избежать слишком легких данных для модели при обучении, по счастливой случайности

Comment: я имел ввиду как раз таки по признакам  и он был связан с ансаблем, я конечно не специалист и могу путать но по моему я где то читал про такой способ , плюс когда я изучал машинное обучение в институте , там говорили про способы обучения и один из них как раз тот который я упомянул , но опять же я могу ошибаться.

Comment: Если вы без библиотек пишите, то могу порекомендовать хорошую книгу там очень все детально и доступно расписано https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135794246/, подробнее и лучше книг я не встречал, она есть в свободном доступе, но более ранние издания, там отличия незначительны

Comment: @АлександрВасильев если вы говорите про деление по признакам, то может быть Вам подойдёт метод случайных подпространств?